# How do you get the Intel 82801JI on-board audio to work in Ubuntu Karmic 9.10?

Tags: linux, alsa

I have a Dell Precision T3500 with the following audio device from `lspci -v`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0293
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at dfffc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
        Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

I've got Ubuntu Karmic 9.10 where I recently upgraded, but haven't really mucked around with the audio settings.

This is what `aplay -l` says:

```
aplay: device_list:223: no soundcards found...
```

Sound used to work before I let the package manager upgrade everything.

I'm running kernel `2.6.31-16-generic-pae`.

Does anyone know why Alsa isn't finding a card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using pulseaudio because it breaks on its own all the time.

The sound card works fine once I added myself to the audio group and rebooted. I removed pulseaudio completely as well.

Not the best solution, but I figure it's just easier to use Alsa which works.